# After changing to developer mode, I am facing the error Element 'remove': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3.5, developer-mode

After changing to developer mode, I am facing the error
**My site is working perfectly until I change it to developer mode**

**Product page & News event page showing error. All other pages are working fine**

**Magento 2.3.5 p1 --- PHP 7.3.3 --- MYSQL 5.7 --- Apache 2.4**

Facing this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
Line: 1592


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'remove': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
Line: 1592

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#00000000043860b1000000003ce7d63e#, array(), NULL, '/var/www/html/na...', '%message%\nLine: ...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#00000000043860b1000000003ce7d63e#, array(), NULL, '/var/www/html/na...', '%message%\nLine: ...')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:108]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/var/www/html/na...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#00000000043860b1000000003ce7d63e#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/var/www/html/na...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#00000000043860b1000000003ce7d63e#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/var/www/html/na...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#00000000043860b1000000003ce7d63e#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:xs...', 'layout_merged', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:512]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend_...', '<body>\n   <refer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:488]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:259]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:884]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_hea...') called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php:215]
#14 Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(&Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor#0000000004386702000000003ce7d63e#, 'no-route') called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Noroute/Index.php:47]
#15 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#17 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#18 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#19 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Noroute/Index/Interceptor.php:26]
#20 Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:162]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#, &Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index\Interceptor#0000000004386702000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:98]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#25 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000004386036000000003ce7d63e#, &Closure#0000000004386055000000003ce7d63e#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#26 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:69]
#27 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor#0000000004386036000000003ce7d63e#, &Closure#0000000004386055000000003ce7d63e#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#28 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#29 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#30 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#0000000004386143000000003ce7d63e#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#00000000043861a7000000003ce7d63e#) called at [index.php:39]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are valid.
**In layout XML**, declaring `<remove` with attribute `name` will make Magento detect `remove` as an element.
You don't see the exception in Production mode because Magento ignores these exceptions to allow the website running but it will throw exceptions in Developer mode.

To remove a block or container, you should reference the block or container which uses `remove` attribute`. For instance, you should use:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<remove name="header.container"/>
<remove name="catalog.topnav"/>
```

To find the files that caused the error, run the following command:

```
grep -r --include \*.xml --exclude-dir=vendor/magento "<remove name=" app vendor
```

**Note:** Only **layout XML** files should be fixed, you can ignore other files type

---

**Update solution based on the new information from the Original Poster**

Based on your updated information, the following files should be updated:

```
app/design/frontend/Nf/Theme2/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:      <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
app/design/frontend/Nf/Theme1/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:      <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
app/code/Custom/Prolayout/view/frontend/layout/custom_catalog_product_view.xml:      <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
```

Because `product.info.addtocart` is a block name, to resolve the issue, open the above files to replace:

```
<remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
```

with

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart" remove="true"/>
```

Finally, clear the `layout` cache type.

Comment: **I am not able to get the error, Got a chunk of code. Sharing it with you through codeshare. As I can't write all the code here due to character limitation**

[link](https://codeshare.io/loR1WR)

Comment: I've updated my answer to support you based on your updated information, please give it a try.

Comment: Thnak you soo much! Solved the problem. But got one problem in another page. Sharing with you the error here.
[link](https://codeshare.io/pqRR76)
Kindly check the issue Thank you

Comment: By running this command: sudo grep -r --include \*.xml "<referenceBlock name=" app vendor

I got these lines of code: [link](https://codeshare.io/eVRRMx)

Comment: In app/code/Custom/Prolayout/view/frontend/layout/my_downlodable_view_id_226.xml, you are trying to comment 2 lines of code`<referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>` and `<referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>` but looks like it comments in the wrong way. So, try commenting on each line like the following instead of 2 lines or remove the code which in unneeded.

Comment: <!--        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.main" remove="true"/>-->

Comment: <!--        <referenceBlock name="sidebar.additional" remove="true"/>-->

Comment: I made it right comment. Still same error. 
`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceBlock', attribute 'name': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'sidebar.additional   ' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z\d\-_\.]*'.
Line: 1153`

Comment: I think you should create a new question, that will help other who has the same issue in the future. In the new question, paste the content of `app/code/Custom/Prolayout/view/frontend/layout/my_downlodable_view_id_226.xml` into your question, I'll take a look.

Comment: @UsmanAhmed also make sure you already removed `layout` cache type whenever you changed the layout xml files.

Comment: Sure! Let me create a new question with all the details. Thank you